# Copy a directory to external HDD

Tags: shell, ubuntu, tar

I'm trying to copy a directory to external HDD. I mounted the device and then typed : `cd root tar -cf - * | (cd /mnt ; tar -xpf -)`

I got this error message: "cowardly refusing to create an empty archive"

When I do `ls` to the same root directory- it is not empty at all- all my needed files are there.

Why does this happen?

Comment: No, you wouldn't have gotten this error message from what you show here (which has only a `cd` command on the left side of the pipe). Copy-paste your actual command.

Comment: [Cross-posted at Ask Ubuntu.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/30154/copy-directory-to-external-hdd) Shira: please [do not cross-post between Stack Exchange sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-it-possible-to-post-questions-across-a-couple-of-the-sites-because-its-debata/64073#64073). This question is suitable for both sites, but pick only one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to copy the root filesystem and worry about special files and devices, the best way is:

- first to mount the / in a subdir using the bind option for mount, this way you won't have to worry about /proc, /dev, /sys and other mounted filesystems
- then use a command that knows how to handle special files, like cp -a or rsync -a

lets say you have mounted the external drive under /mnt/external

```
mkdir /mnt/root
mount / /mnt/root -o bind
cp -a /mnt/root/* /mnt/external/
```

or

```
rsync -aP /mnt/root/ /mnt/external/
```

or (if you like tar so much, btw the worst option)

```
tar -C /mnt/root -cf - ./ | tar -C /mnt/external -xpf -
```

add -v to any of the above for verbose output, but it will slow down a bit the process

Comment: thank you very much!!!- btw i didn't use tar..........

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you simply use `cp -pr source destination`?

Anyway:

```
cd ~/tmp/source/;tar -cpf - * | (cd ~/tmp/destination;tar -xpf -)
```

works just fine.

Comment: Err, I'm guessing 'distance' should be 'destination'. Or possibly 'distant directory'.

Comment: LOL, I have no idea how that got there.

Answer (score 2):

I find the best thing for copying whole directory structures is `rsync`

```
# rsync -avP /path/to/source/* /path/to/destination/
```

This also has the advantage that you can to it to or from a remote directory through ssh.

Answer (score 2):

Please use the POSIX [PAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pax_%28Unix%29) utility.

Unlike cp, **pax works the same on every system**. With pax you can always safely copy file systems with special files such as device nodes.

To copy one file system /mnt/foo into /mnt/bar, preserving permissions, timestamps and special files do:

```
# cd /mnt/foo
pax -rw -pe -X . /mnt/bar/
```